# Showing independence of $Y/X$ and $X$ where $(X,Y)$ is uniform on a triangle.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be r.v.s with the uniform distribution on the triangle $A$ = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1\}$. 
So $d\mu_{(X,Y)}(x,y)= 2\mathbf{1}_A(x,y)dxdy$.

I found that $P(Y/X\leq k)=k$ when $k \in (0,1)$. How do I use this to show that $X$ and $Y/X$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to find the distribution of $Y/X$ to show independence, and in fact the distribution will be obvious from the proof. Fix $j$ and $k$, and we want to calculate

$$P\Big( X\le j, \, Y/X \le k\ \Big) = \iint_{A_{j,k}} 2 \, dxdy,$$

where $A_{j,k}:= \big\{ (x,y) \,:\, x\le j, \, y/x \le k \big\}$. Use the change of variables $(x,y) = (u,uv)$ (which we could rewrite as $(u,v) = (x,y/x)$). One has

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{dx}{du} & \frac{dx}{dv} \\
\frac{dy}{du} & \frac{dy}{dv}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
v & u
\end{bmatrix}, $$

so the Jacobian of the transformation is $u$. Note that $(x,y)\in A_{j,k}$ if and only if $0 \le u \le j$, $0 \le v \le k$. Hence,

$$P\Big( X\le j, \, Y/X \le k\ \Big) = 2\int_0^j \int_0^{k/u} u\,dvdu = 2k\int_0^j u\, du = j^2k.$$

Since this is a function of $j$ times a function of $k$, it follows that $X$ and $Y/X$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks, if you would want to calculate the conditional  $E[Y|X]$ would you use $\int yf_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_X(x)dy$?

Comment: You could, but since you have shown $X$ and $Y/X$ are independent, it will be much easier to instead write $E[Y|X] = E[X\cdot Y/X|X] = X\cdot E[Y/X]$.

Comment: Should $P(X\leq j,Y/X\leq k)=j^2k?$, so $X$ is not uniform?

Comment: Apologies, there was an error in the calculation. You are correct about the distribution of $X$.